# How to determine ideal Datagram settings

Tags: java, udp

I'm writing a Java client application that will consume high rate UDP data and I want to minimize packet loss at the host/application layer (I understand there may be unavoidable loss in the network layer).

What is a reasobaly high Buffer Size (MulticastSocket.setReceiverBufferSize())?

What is the ideal DatagramPacket buffer size?  Is there a downside to using 64k?

I have very limited insight into the network topology and the sender application.  This is running on Linux.  TCP is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

> What is a reasobaly high Buffer Size (MulticastSocket.setReceiverBufferSize())?

Figure out how much your application might jitter and the rate of data you need to receive. e.g. if your application pauses to do something for 0.5 seconds (like garbage collection), and you're receiving data at 10MB/sec, you'd need a buffer of 5MB to make up for not receiving data for those 0.5 seconds.

Note that you might need to tune the `net.core.rmem_max` sysctl on linux to be allowed to set the buffers to the desired size(iirc you actually only get half the size of what you specify in the sysctl) , the default net.core.rmem_max might be rather low.

> What is the ideal DatagramPacket buffer size? Is there a downside to using 64k?

The ideal is that of the [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) of your network, for normal ethernet, that means an UDP payload of 1472 bytes. Anything bigger is a bad idea, as it causes fragmented IP packet - IP fragmentation is generally considered a bad thing, as it causes more overhead and can cause more lost data.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets end and receive buffers can be as large as you like, a megabyte or two if you want.

The maximum practical datagram size via a router is 534 bytes.